# Deletion on Balancing Binary Tree

Tags: c, struct, binary-tree

I'm having a code for inserting data into a balancing binary tree, so the example is, if I enter these inputs:

```
20, 10, 30, 5, 15, 25, 4
```

I expect the tree after input would look like this:

```
         20
     /        \
    10        30
   /  \     /    \
  5   15   25     4
```

So, when deleting, everything works fine except deleting 4 
4 belongs to the case 1 in Delete function, 
Question is, I can't understand why does deletion 4 doesn't work, but when I delete 5, 15, 25, it works?

I got the Delete function from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gcULXE7ViZw 
It's for binary search tree, but I thought it would cause no problem even if it is used in a Binary Tree

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<conio.h>

struct node{

    int data, balance;

    struct node *left, *right;

};

int insert(struct node **root, struct node **curr, int data){

    struct node *newNode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newNode -> data = data;
    newNode -> left = NULL;
    newNode -> right = NULL;
    newNode -> balance = 0;

    if((*root) == NULL){
        (*root) = (*curr) = newNode;
        (*root) -> left = NULL;
        (*root) -> right = NULL;
        return 0;
    } else {
        if((*curr)->left == NULL && (*curr)->balance == 0){
            (*curr) -> balance = (*curr) -> balance - 1;
            (*curr) -> left = newNode;
            return 0;
        } else if ((*curr)->right == NULL && (*curr)->balance == -1){
            (*curr) -> balance = (*curr) -> balance + 1;
            (*curr) -> right = newNode;
            return 0;
        } else if ((*curr)->balance == 0 && (*curr)->left->balance == 0){
            (*curr) -> balance = (*curr) -> balance - 1;
            (*curr) = (*curr)->left;
            return insert(root,curr,data);
        } else if ((*curr)->balance < 0 && (*curr)->left->balance < 0){
            (*curr) -> balance = (*curr) -> balance - 1;
            (*curr) = (*curr) -> left;
            return insert(root,curr,data);
        } else if ((*curr)->balance < 0 && (*curr)->left->balance == 0){
            (*curr) -> balance = (*curr) -> balance + 1;
            (*curr) = (*curr)->right;
            return insert(root, curr, data);
        }
    }
}

void preorder(struct node *root){

    if(root == NULL) return;
    printf("%d ", root->data);
    preorder(root->left);
    preorder(root->right);

}

void postorder(struct node *root){

    if(root == NULL) return;
    postorder(root->left);
    postorder(root->right);
    printf("%d ", root->data);

}

void inorder(struct node *root){

    if(root == NULL) return;
    inorder(root->left);
    printf("%d ", root->data);
    inorder(root->right);

}

void search(struct node *root, int *key, int *found){

    if(root == NULL) return;
    search(root->left, key, found);
    if(root->data == *key){
        *found = 1;
        return ;
    }
    search(root->right, key, found);

}

struct node *findMin(struct node *root){

    while(root->left != NULL) root = root->left;
    return root;
}

struct node *Delete(struct node *root, int data){

    if(root == NULL) return root;
    else if(data < root->data) root->left = Delete(root->left, data);
    else if(data > root->data) root->right = Delete(root->right, data);
    else {
        //Case 1: no child / leaf node
        if(root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL){
            free(root);
            root = NULL;
        }
        //Case 2: one child, left or right
        else if(root->left == NULL){
            struct node *temp = root;
            root = root->right;
            free(temp);
        } else if (root->right == NULL){
            struct node *temp = root;
            root = root->left;
            free(temp);
        }
        //Case 3: two children
        else{
            struct node *temp = findMin(root->right);
            root->data = temp->data;
            root->right = Delete(root->right, temp->data);
        }
    }
    return root;
}


int main(){

    struct node *root, *curr;
    int choice, data, key, found, delKey;
    root = curr = NULL;

    while(1){
        found = 0;
        printf("Balanced Binary Tree Menu\n");
        printf("1. Insert Data\n");
        printf("2. View on pre order\n");
        printf("3. View on post order\n");
        printf("4. View on in order\n");
        printf("5. Search\n");
        printf("6. Delete\n");
        printf("7. Exit\n");
        printf("Pilihan: ");scanf("%d", &choice);fflush(stdin);

        if(choice == 1){
            printf("Enter data : "); scanf("%d", &data);
            curr = root;
            insert(&root, &curr, data);
        } else if (choice == 2){
            preorder(root);
            system("pause");
        } else if (choice == 3){
            postorder(root);
            system("pause");
        } else if (choice == 4){
            inorder(root);
            system("pause");
        } else if (choice == 5){
            printf("Search: "); scanf("%d", &key);
            search(root, &key, &found);
            if(found == 1){
                printf("Data found !\n");
            } else {
                printf("Data not found !\n");
            }
            system("pause");
        } else if (choice == 6){
            curr = root;
            printf("Data : ");
            preorder(root);
            printf("\n\n");
            printf("Enter data to be deleted: "); scanf("%d", &delKey);
            Delete(curr, delKey);
            printf("Data after deletion : ");
            preorder(root);
            system("pause");

        } else if (choice == 7){
            return 1;
        }
        system("cls");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: in 20, 10, 30, 5, 15, 4 there is no 25, how it can be in the produced tree ? *insert* does not return a value in all cases. Alter a delete a balanced tree must stay balanced, if you use an other algorithm it will  not. if you insert in order 20, 10, 30, 5, 15 and 4 and you view in order the result is "5 10 15 20 4 30" which is already wrong, the problem is not only in the delete part

Comment: @bruno oh I forgot to write the 25 input, I'm gonna edit the code.  Isn't the in order result is left-parent-right, so it's printing the right result?

Comment: you have pre and post order, seems logical "in order" produces the value sorted no ?

Comment: I was intending the inorder to just print the data according to the tree, so the data doesn't supposed to be sorted actually.

Comment: how can you delete supposing the data are ordered in the tree if this is not the case ?

Comment: the data is deleted by searching at its location in the tree, and then see the case, wether the node have children or not, but my search is wrong apparently

Answer (score 0):

the problem lies in the delete function. you perform the deletion as a binary search tree. So, from the root node (20 in your example), it proceeds to search for 4 in the left children.
so the code starts at 20, goes to 10 and then 5 and then it stops because it doesn't find 4.

So you need to change the strategy of your search in the delete (an inorder, postorder, preorder or level order traversal). Just keep in mind your tree isn't a binary search tree; it is just balanced. So you need to look at every node when you want to delete.

Comment: Hello there @Shobhit Kumar I have try using inorder traversal, and found the root where the data is. but when it tried to delete 4 from my example, it shows  the result : 25 10 5 15 4 25 .  Can you explain how to look at every node when i want to delete ?