# Why does my binary tree search function not return the root adress?

Tags: c, struct, binary-tree

I'm sorry for asking too much, so this is almost the same with my previous questions. 
I have a balancing binary tree code with deletion function, so the problem is in my searchdelete() function. I don't know why it won't return the root back. So for example

```
5, 4, 3, 2, 1
```

And then i input on the menu "Data to be deleted: `1`" 
it goes to the searchdelete(); function, and then it successfully 
shows that the data is found, `found = 1`
but after that, it just won't return the root address. I have no idea why it won't return. 
So in the Delete(); function, it wont print the `printf("root after = %d", root->data)`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<conio.h>

struct node{

    int data, balance;

    struct node *left, *right;

};

int insert(struct node **root, struct node **curr, int data){

    struct node *newNode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newNode -> data = data;
    newNode -> left = NULL;
    newNode -> right = NULL;
    newNode -> balance = 0;

    if((*root) == NULL){
        (*root) = (*curr) = newNode;
        (*root) -> left = NULL;
        (*root) -> right = NULL;
        return 0;
    } else {
        if((*curr)->left == NULL && (*curr)->balance == 0){
            (*curr) -> balance = (*curr) -> balance - 1;
            (*curr) -> left = newNode;
            return 0;
        } else if ((*curr)->right == NULL && (*curr)->balance == -1){
            (*curr) -> balance = (*curr) -> balance + 1;
            (*curr) -> right = newNode;
            return 0;
        } else if ((*curr)->balance == 0 && (*curr)->left->balance == 0){
            (*curr) -> balance = (*curr) -> balance - 1;
            (*curr) = (*curr)->left;
            return insert(root,curr,data);
        } else if ((*curr)->balance < 0 && (*curr)->left->balance < 0){
            (*curr) -> balance = (*curr) -> balance - 1;
            (*curr) = (*curr) -> left;
            return insert(root,curr,data);
        } else if ((*curr)->balance < 0 && (*curr)->left->balance == 0){
            (*curr) -> balance = (*curr) -> balance + 1;
            (*curr) = (*curr)->right;
            return insert(root, curr, data);
        }
    }
}

void preorder(struct node *root){

    if(root == NULL) return;
    printf("%d ", root->data);
    preorder(root->left);
    preorder(root->right);

}

void postorder(struct node *root){

    if(root == NULL) return;
    postorder(root->left);
    postorder(root->right);
    printf("%d ", root->data);

}

void inorder(struct node *root){

    if(root == NULL) return;
    inorder(root->left);
    printf("%d ", root->data);
    inorder(root->right);

}


void search(struct node *root, int *key, int *found){

    if(root == NULL) return;
    search(root->left, key, found);
    if(root->data == *key){
        *found = 1;
        return ;
    }
    search(root->right, key, found);

}

struct node *findMin(struct node *root){

    while(root->left != NULL) root = root->left;
    return root;
}

struct node *searchdelete(struct node *root, int data){

    if(root == NULL) return root;                                    //This is the searchdelete
    searchdelete(root->left, data);
    if(root->data == data){
        printf("found = %d", root->data);
        return root;
    }
    searchdelete(root->right, data);

}

struct node *Delete(struct node *root, int data){

    printf("root before = %d\n", root->data);
    if(root == NULL) return root;
    else if(data != root->data) {
        root = searchdelete(root, data);
        printf("root after = %d\n", root->data);           //this is where it won't print
        system("pause");
    }
    else{
        //Case 1: no child / leaf node
        if(root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL){
            printf("NULL\n");
            free(root);
            root = NULL;
        }
        //Case 2: one child, left or right
        else if(root->left == NULL){
            printf("left null\n");
            struct node *temp = root;
            root = root->right;
            free(temp);
        } else if (root->right == NULL){
            printf("right null\n");
            struct node *temp = root;
            root = root->left;
            free(temp);
        }
        //Case 3: two children
        else{
            printf("two children \n");
            if(root->right->data > root->data){
                struct node *temp = root;
                root = root->right;
                free(temp);
            } else {
                struct node *temp = root;
                root = root->left;
                free(temp);
            }
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return root;
}


int main(){

    struct node *root, *curr;
    int choice, data, key, found, delKey;
    root = curr = NULL;

    while(1){
        found = 0;
        printf("Balanced Binary Tree Menu\n");
        printf("1. Insert Data\n");
        printf("2. View on pre order\n");
        printf("3. View on post order\n");
        printf("4. View on in order\n");
        printf("5. Search\n");
        printf("6. Delete\n");
        printf("7. Exit\n");
        printf("Pilihan: ");scanf("%d", &choice);fflush(stdin);

        if(choice == 1){
            printf("Enter data : "); scanf("%d", &data);
            curr = root;
            insert(&root, &curr, data);
        } else if (choice == 2){
            preorder(root);
            system("pause");
        } else if (choice == 3){
            postorder(root);
            system("pause");
        } else if (choice == 4){
            inorder(root);
            system("pause");
        } else if (choice == 5){
            printf("Search: "); scanf("%d", &key);
            search(root, &key, &found);
            if(found == 1){
                printf("Data found !\n");
            } else {
                printf("Data not found !\n");
            }
            system("pause");
        } else if (choice == 6){
            printf("Enter data to be deleted: "); scanf("%d", &delKey);
            Delete(root, delKey);
        } else if (choice == 7){
            return 1;
        }
        system("cls");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possibly because you're missing a `return` at the end of function `searchdelete`.

Comment: you also have a missing `return` in *insert*, I already signaled it in the first remark of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61422943/deletion-on-balancing-binary-tree

Comment: @goodvibration but if i add ```return root;``` at the end ```searchdelete``` it won't return the address that have ```1```

Comment: @bruno i have add ```return 0``` in insert, but it still won't return root

Comment: I meant you should add `return` before `searchdelete(root->right, data);`.

Comment: two `return` are missing in your definition, look at my answer

Answer (score 1):

> Why does my binary tree search function not return the root adress?
>
> I have no idea why it won't return.

because 2 `return` are missing

Can be:

```
struct node * searchdelete(struct node *root, int data){
    if(root == NULL)
      return root;
    if(root->data == data){
        printf("found = %d", root->data); /* debug, to be removed */
        return root;
    }
    if ((root = searchdelete(root->left, data)) != NULL)
      return root;
    return searchdelete(root->right, data);
}
```

In *search* why *key* is an `int*` rather than just an `int` like for *searchdelete* ? For me he function *search* is useless, *searchdelete* is already enough to know if the key is present in the tree just calling it and comparing its return value with NULL. So better to remove *search* and to rename *searchdelete* to be *search* (or *find*)

In both functions you search without using the fact the tree can be sorted, I mean on the left the data are less, on the right they are greater, that improves the performance

There is no interest at all to have a binary tree if the elements are randomly placed in

---

Your definition of *Delete* has a lot of problems, including undefined behavior because you free cells without removing them from the tree

Comment: I have added the 2 ```return``` but it still won't return the root. yup in Search ```key``` should just be ```int```, i was testing to make the search function first. 
And for the tree, it is placed randomly, it's just for making a binary tree, not binary search tree.

Comment: @ChristianHalim if you use my definition you get the cell containing the key (so obviourly not the root of all the tree we do not care) or NULL if not present, I do not know what error you did when getting it ...

Comment: Yes, i also thought the return would give the cell that containing the key, but I don't see any error, and it always stops when i tried to print the cell containing the key too

Comment: @ChristianHalim your question is about your search functions, I corrected them, out of that your *Delete* function is wrong too (I edited my answer to a remark at the end), but this is an other question no ?

Comment: yes I was only asking about the search function, would you mind if I ask what's wrong with the delete function too?

Comment: I also don't understand, why does ```printf("root after = %d\n", root->data);``` after root = searchdeletion(); won't print anything

Comment: @ChristianHalim you can add a new question for *Delete* , but you already have one for it. Clearly you do not need to have a *search* function called in *Delete* because after you need again to search to modify your tree. You do not have your *printf* because your algorithm in *Delete* is wrong

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't get it . . . I thought that if my searchdelete(); could return the ```root``` which contain the ```key```, at least it would printf the data, because it's not entering the ```case``` in the Delete function, but it's not printing anything, can you tell me which part is wrong with the Delete algorithm ?